# Not able to access constant from parent class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to access the constant from parent class but getting error

**NameError: uninitialized constant CONSTS**

This is my code - parent class

```
module Abc
  class Xyz
    class A
      class CONSTS
        ONE = "1"
        TWO = "2"
        Three = "3"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the child class

```
module Abc
  class Xyz
    class B < A
      class << self
        def print_const
          get_const
        end

        private

        def get_const
          puts CONSTS::ONE
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when i try Abc:Xyz::B.print_const i am getting the above error.

can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: downvoted for use of lowercase module and class names.

Comment: @AshishSaihgal: corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `a::CONSTS:ONE` or the full identifier `::abc::xyz::a::CONSTS:ONE`.

Comment: i know that, but why i am not able to access constant derived in parent class?
moreover i feel its not a right way to access constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, smth like that

```
...
def get_const
  puts self.class.superclass::CONSTS::ONE
end
...
```